# Tablesorter zebra doesnt stripe till sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, tablesorter

I have my tables and they are great I can sort them and it works wonderfully except that  they don't do the zebra striping until I sort them for the first time. My understanding was that they will be striped as soon as table sorter is initialized, is this not the case?

This is tablesorter v 2.10 (the latest) from here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html

Comment: Seems to work okay for me... Are you sure you have all the resources loaded?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is most probably related to the fact that the table is not visible (`display: none`) when you initialize the tablesorter on your table.

A possible solution is to execute the following initialization only once the table is visible with:

```
if($('tab_parent_of_the_table').is(':visible')) {
    $("your_table_table").tablesorter({
       widgets: ['zebra']
    });
}
```

An even better solution is to wrap the visibility check with a timeout, since normally it is done before the change of visibility is applied, resulting in a false statement.
Do like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if($('tab_parent_of_the_table').is(':visible')) {
        $("your_table_table").tablesorter({
           widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Once the table is visible, you can apply the zebra widget using `$('#your-table').trigger('update', [true])`

Comment: The official documentation recommends using `$('#your-table').trigger('applyWidgets');` ( https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-zebra.html )

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem is that if your tables are hidden either with `display: none` or a parent of the table is hidden with `display: none` then the zebra widget is not applied until the first sort.

Comment: Once the table is visible, you can apply the zebra widget using `$('#your-table').trigger('update', [true])`

Answer (score 1):

With most browsers supporting CSS3, you don't really need to use the zebra widget anymore, unless you plan on filtering rows (see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html)).

Otherwise, try css that looks something like this:

```
table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
table tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: Ya thats the thing is I do need to support filtering

Comment: Well, then you just need to use the [`applyWidgets` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#applywidgets) whenever the table becomes visible - e.g. see [this answer](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/224#issuecomment-13086515) on how to use tablesorter within jQuery UI tabs.

Comment: Is there any reason why it won't bother to try doing a zebra while its hidden?

Comment: It's difficult to distinguish the difference between a table row being hidden by filtering or pagination versus the row being hidden because it is within a closed tab. Also, no zebra stripe class name is applied to hidden rows because it would only add more of a delay to apply the widget after each sort - this would be especially noticeable in large tables.